# Change select options based on first select option choice by PHP AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database

```
<select class="one"></select>
<select class="two"></select>
```

Here are my two select options I need to change options of select 2 based on my selection from select 1

**Note :** The two options of those two selects are coming from the database

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax in this case. please refer the following example here I am taking states according to the country :

Ajax code :

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{ url('getStates')}}",
       data: {
            country: $(this).val(),
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
       success : function(data){
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            var option = '<option value="">--- state ---</option>';
            for(var i in data){
                option += '<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
            }
            $("#state").html(option);
       }
    });

});
```

Php code :

```
public function getStates(Request $request)
    {
        $states = DB::table('states')
            ->where('country_id', $request->country)
            ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        echo json_encode($states);
    }
```